# Find a vector equation for the line through the point $(3,-8,-8)$ perpendicular to these vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Find a vector equation for the line through the point $(3,-8,-8)$ perpendicular to these vectors $u=\langle 2,2,-1\rangle$ and $v=\langle -9,-8,-3\rangle$.

I'm fairly new to vector equations. Would I find a component vector of $u$ and $v$ and write the parametric equation for it and then use the formula $r(t) = r_0 + tv$?

Comment: The easiest way to find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is perpendicular to two vectors $u$ and $v$, is to compute $u\times v$ (the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product))

Comment: @robjohn why the cross product?

Comment: $u\times v$ is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$. This can be seen from the triple products $u\times v\cdot u=0$, which is the determinant of a matrix with columns of $u$, $v$, and $u$, and $u\times v\cdot v=0$, which is the determinant of a matrix with columns of $u$, $v$, and $v$. Both of these determinants are $0$ since each matrix has two identical columns.

Comment: @robjohn my textbook _defines_ the cross product $u\times v$ to be a vector perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$ and with magnitude $|u||v|\sin (\widehat{u,v})$.

Comment: @user31415: yes, but somehow, it seemed a bit artless to say, "because it's defined that way" :-) However, yes; it is defined that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch.

The best way to approach this is by thinking about what fundamentally defines a line: a vector and a point. In this case, we have the point, but instead of a vector in the direction of the line, we have two vectors perpendicular to the line. However, if we take the cross product of these two vectors, it will by definition be perpendicular to both of them and thus be in the direction of the line itself. Taking the cross product gives $\langle -14, 15, 2\rangle$. Then, the line can be parametrized using standard techniques as

$$\langle 3,-8,-8\rangle+t\cdot \langle-14, 15, 2\rangle=\langle 3-14t, -8+15t, -8+2t\rangle.$$

Comment: Ohhh, ok so the cross product gives a vector perpendicular to BOTH u and v? So that makes it the "opposite" and makes it parallel to the line we want to find

Comment: Yes, the cross product of two vectors is always perpendicular to both.

Comment: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = (3,-8,-8)$ be the point given above, $u$ and $v$ be defined as above, and $O = (0,0,0)$ (origin).  Let $O \rightarrow P$ denote the distance from the origin to $P$.  The cross product of two vectors results in a perpendicular vector.  Hence $u \times v = (-14,15,2)$.  Thus the equation for the line through the point $P$ perpendicular to $u$ and $v$ is

$r(t) = O\rightarrow P + t(-14,15,2) = (3,-8,-8) + t(-14,15,2)$

where $O \rightarrow P = P - O$.